# Programmatically Add Entry to shoppinglist.google.com

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Obviously there is no REST API implementation for the google shoppinglist .
So I am trying to add items to the list programmatically like:

```
var f = document.querySelector("#gxMainContent > list-page > shopping-list > div > add-list-item-input > form > input");
f.value = 'My new entry';
var b = document.querySelector("#gxMainContent > list-page > shopping-list > div > add-list-item-input > form > button");
b.click();
```

But no matter which click event I am triggering, that value entered is not being added to the list.
Can anyone help me to solve this?

So the background is, that I am extracting ingredients for a recipe on a website which I want to add to the shoppinglist programmatically. I just don't know how to submit the button on the shoppinglist to add a new entry to the list.

Any help would be appreciated.